# What does the phrase “flight attendants: stand by for all call” mean?

Tags: flight-attendant

At the end of an announcement on a recent flight, a crew member said: “flight attendants stand by for all call”.  What did the crew member mean and what exactly were the flight attendants waiting for?

Answer (score 1):

"Flight attendants stand by for all call" commands the cabin crew to be ready at their station to report to the  chief purser via intercom.

See the explanation on this and other airline phraseology on
[askthepilot.com](https://www.askthepilot.com/how-to-speak-airline/)

Answer (score 0):

“Flight attendants, prepare doors for departure, cross check, and all call”

Meaning: each flight attendant will go to their assigned door and arm the slide/raft incase of an emergency Evacuation

(Usually announced after jet bridge pulls away)